# XMl parsing in c# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

i have the following xml to be parsed

```
<config>
<ParametricTesting>Y</ParametericTesting>
<FunctionalTesting>Y</FunctionalTesting>
<Utilities>N</Utilities>
<CommonApi>N</CommonApi>
<ClientData>N</ClientData>
<DataSourceTest>Y<DataSourceTest>
<Excel>
 <ExcelFilePath>myexcel1.xlsx</ExcelFilePath>
</Excel>
<Access>
 <AccessDB> </AccessDB>
</Access>
<Sql>
<SqlConnectionString> </SqlConnectionString>
</Sql>
<RunnerConsole>N</RunnerConsole>
<Schedular>N</Schedular>
</config>
```

I am using xmlreader to read the xml but since i am new to c# so i don't know why the code is breaking after reading second tag i.e ParametericTesting.

code:

```
string ConfigXml = Path.GetFullPath("Config.xml");
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(ConfigXml);

while (xmlReader.Read()) {
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType== XmlNodeType.Element) && xmlReader.Name.Equals("ParametricTesting")) {
        // TODO : write code relevant for parametric testing 
        xmlReader.Read();
    }
    else if ((xmlReader.NodeType== XmlNodeType.Element)&& xmlReader.Name.Equals("DataSourceTest")) {
        string Datasource = xmlReader.GetAttribute("DataSourceTest");

        if (Datasource.Equals("Y")) {
            if (xmlReader.Name.Equals("Excel") && (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)) {
                string excelfile = xmlReader.GetAttribute("ExcelFilePath");
                string ExcelPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Files\\" + excelfile;
                objExcel.DataSourceName = excelfile; 
                objExcel.Open();
            }
        }
        xmlReader.Read();
    }
    xmlReader.Read();
}
```

My code is not reading element beyond parametricTesting . Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you open tag of "ParametricTesting" in the config.xml is different from the closing tag. correct it and that line passes.

also, you don't close the tag "DataSourceTest"

here is the fixed XML:

```
<config>
   <ParametricTesting>Y</ParametricTesting>
   <FunctionalTesting>Y</FunctionalTesting>
   <Utilities>N</Utilities>
   <CommonApi>N</CommonApi>
   <ClientData>N</ClientData>
   <DataSourceTest>Y</DataSourceTest>
   <Excel>
    <ExcelFilePath>myexcel1.xlsx</ExcelFilePath>
   </Excel>
   <Access>
    <AccessDB> </AccessDB>
   </Access>
   <Sql>
      <SqlConnectionString> </SqlConnectionString>
   </Sql>
   <RunnerConsole>N</RunnerConsole>
   <Schedular>N</Schedular>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked oh such a silly mistake but now i am not able to fetch the attribute value correctly Am i fetching it correctly via already written code or some changes need to be done.

Comment: @priya that's i'm here for :)